# Quotation Marks and \ in Bash Scripting with sed command

Tags: bash, variables, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Im writing a bash script to help me set up my rpi's network interfaces faster. It is mostly finished now and works using sed to alter different parts of the /etc/network/interfaces files depending how the network interface is being set up. My problem is that i am inserting quotation marks where i don't want them and if i remove the quotation marks i insert the variables containing the data to be inserted as a string of the variable name as oppose to inserting them as their value.

My code is as followed (although i have cut it down)

```
#!/bin/bash
ANS=''
ssid=''
psk=''
file='/etc/network/interfaces'
ip=''
netmask=''
broadcast=''
gateway=''
function static {
    echo 'Will now set up Static IP'
    echo 'What IP address do you want to assign this Device?'
    echo -e '> \c'
    read ip
    echo 'What is your Networks Netmask/Subnet?'
    echo -e '> \c'
    read netmask
        echo 'What is your Networks Broadcast Address?'
        echo -e '> \c'
        read broadcast
        echo 'What is the address of your Networks Gateway?'
        echo -e '> \c'
        read gateway
    echo 'You entered the following information about your Network'
    echo ''
    echo 'Address: ' $ip
    echo 'Netmask: ' $netmask
    echo 'Broadcast: ' $broadcast
    echo 'Gateway: ' $gateway
    echo 'Is this information correct? (y/n)'
    echo -e '> \c'
        read ANS
        if [ $ANS = 'y' ]; then
        sed -i "s/^iface eth0 inet dhcp.*\$/iface eth0 inet static/" $file
        sed -i "s/^#    address.*\$/    address \"$ip\"/" $file
        sed -i "s/^#    netmask.*\$/    netmask \"$netmask\"/" $file
        sed -i "s/^#    broadcast.*\$/  broadcast \"$broadcast\"/" $file
        sed -i "s/^#    gateway.*\$/    gateway \"$gateway\"/" $file
        echo 'Static IP address has now been set up'
        start
    else
        static
    fi
}
```

The problem is these lines here

```
        sed -i "s/^#    address.*\$/    address \"$ip\"/" $file
        sed -i "s/^#    netmask.*\$/    netmask \"$netmask\"/" $file
        sed -i "s/^#    broadcast.*\$/  broadcast \"$broadcast\"/" $file
        sed -i "s/^#    gateway.*\$/    gateway \"$gateway\"/" $file
```

which insert `address "(var_address)"`. As i said i can get it to insert `address $address`. But not, as i want, `address (var_address)`. Could someone please explain how to use the / and \ together with " and ' in the sed command so that i can fix the problem. As you may have guessed im a bit of a newb to bash so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a concrete example, what your expected output should be? Do you really want the literal string `address (var_address)` in your output instead of `address 138.18.7.88`?

Comment: As in address 192.168.1.255 or whatever sos that wasn't clear

Comment: Then I don't understand your problem, just leave out `\$` and all `\"`. You can also reduce the number of sed calls by using `sed -i -e 's/.../' -e 's/.../' $file`

Comment: so does the \$var mean literally print/change $var as oppose to print/change 192.168.1.255

Comment: Yes, `\$` escapes the `$` and prevents the use of `var` as a variable. However, in your case, the `\$` is part of the regex, but is unnecessary, because you already have `.*`, which extends as far as possible.

Comment: oh i get that know - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While bash won't try to resolv no standard variables, like `$/`, you could simply:

```
sed "
    /^iface $iface/,/^$/{
        /address/s/^.*$/\taddress $ip/;
        /netmask/s/^.*$/\tnetmask $netmask/;
        /broadcast/s/^.*$/\tbroadcast $broadcast/;
        /gateway/s/^.*$/\tgateway $gateway/;

    }" -i $file
```

Nota: This modify **only 1 paragraph** concerning `$iface`: with the first sed line: `/^iface $iface/,/^$/{ ... }` delimit a command block who could be executed only from a line matching `/^iface $iface/` to an empty line (or end of file).

And for playing with IP address in bash, take a look at https://serverfault.com/a/461831/142978

Comment: thanks for the help - this method makes it easier than having to change each line

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what's desired properly, this should work:

```
sed -i "s/^#    address.*\$/    address $ip/" $file
sed -i "s/^#    netmask.*\$/    netmask $netmask/" $file
sed -i "s/^#    broadcast.*\$/  broadcast $broadcast/" $file
sed -i "s/^#    gateway.*\$/    gateway $gateway/" $file
```